# Avro Schema: force to interpret value (map, array) as string

Tags: json, avro, apache-nifi

I want to convert JSON to Avro via NiFi. Unfortunately the JSON has complex types as values that I want to see as a simple string!

JSON:

```
"FLAGS" : {"FLAG" : ["STORED","ACTIVE"]}
```

How can I tell AVRO to simply store "{"FLAG" : ["STORED","ACTIVE"]}" or "[1,2,3,"X"]" as a string?

Thank you sincerely!

Answer (score 3):

The JSON to Avro conversion performed in NiFi's [ConvertJSONToAvro](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.kite.ConvertJSONToAvro/index.html) processor does not really do transformation in the same step.  There is a very limited ability to transform based on the Avro schema, mostly omitting input data fields in the output.  But it won't coerce a complex structure to a string.

Instead, you should do a JSON-to-JSON transformation first, then convert your summarized JSON to Avro.  I think what you are looking for is a structure like this:

```
{
  "FLAGS": "{\"FLAG\":[\"STORED\",\"ACTIVE\"]}"
}
```

NiFi's [JoltTransformJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html), [ExecuteScript](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processors are great for this.  If your records are simple enough, maybe even a combination of [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) `$.FLAGS` and [ReplaceText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) `{ "FLAGS": "${flags:escapeJson()}" }`.

Comment: we had some trouble with JOLT - there were unexplained errors... some data would transform fine - almost identical data did not... as far as I could figure the problem was special characters...